# Latin abbreviation for "see there"

Tags: citations, citation-style, latin

I am writing a paper and want to reference another source. In academic Hebrew, this would be said using the abbreviations for, "*See* (source)" or "as explained in (source), *see there*". Is there a comparable abbreviation in latin?

Comment: Why do you want to write it in Latin? If you don't already know the abbreviation, it's likely unfamiliar to your readers. Are you writing in Hebrew?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Clearly, the paper is being written in Latin. :)

Comment: it is indeed unclear if you are writing a paper "_in latin_", or if you're writing it in English and simply wonder if there is a latin phrase in common use for this purpose. If it's the latter, the standard is to simply use something like "Most academics think X (see [1-3])".   (but, as one of the answers points out, you use "cf." if your aim is explicitly to compare/contrast, rather than simply point the reader to a source)

Comment: We have a [Latin language](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) sister site

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two answers already, both of which can be correct, depending on context (as @AppliedAcademic commented on one of them).

As I mentioned in a comment, We have a [Latin language](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

I think that the best explanation is the accepted answer to [this English language & uasge question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25252/how-does-one-correctly-use-q-v), (q.v) which I quote here in its entity:

> q.v. stands for the phrase   quod vide : "on this (matter) go see"
>
> Cf. is used chiefly to refer to articles proving or documenting one's
> point or having authority, not to avoid treating a particular aspect
> in the course of the writing.
>
> Compared to cf., most authors restrict the use of q.v. to refer to
> another part of the same work (usually a book) where they treat with
> the subject matter. This is also used to advise the reader to read
> another work they endorse.
>
> In a monograph or a large book there is seldom one perfect way of
> serially organizing all content. q.v. is a means for the author to
> help readers learn more at their leisure.
>
> - without making footnotes
> - without distracting or boring people already knowledgeable
> - without repeating part of the material
>
> On critical editions, you will sometimes find q.v. in margin comments
> or apostilles as a quick comment for a quote, giving its source.

Comment: Tip: If you forget what c.f. means, read it as if it's short for "see for [example]".

Comment: "`The abbreviation cf. (short for the Latin: confer/conferatur, both meaning 'compare') is used in writing to refer the reader to other material to make a comparison with the topic being discussed. Style guides recommend that cf. be used only to suggest a comparison, and the word 'see' be used to point to a source of information" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.

Answer (score 27):

Quod vide, q.v. in short.

I agree with the other commenters though, its pretty obscure in English writing.

Answer (score 19):

*Confer*, or *conferatur*, abbreviated as `cf.`

[Cf. the information here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.).

Comment: A minor difference is that cf. is traditionally used to indicate comparison with the current work, rather than for a parent source of the current work. That's mentioned in your linked article.:)

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't use Latin abbreviations unless you're writing in Latin, or the journal's style guide says otherwise.

Simply put, most journals' style guide will dictate the use of a particular referencing style, which will include a particular method of in-text references. For instance, in a paper using the [APA referencing style](https://guides.libraries.psu.edu/apaquickguide/intext), you might write "According to Miller (2019), most foos bar" or "Most foos bar (Miller, 2019)", while in a paper using the [IEEE referencing style](https://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/gettingstarted), you might write "According to [23], most foos bar" or "Most foos bar [23]".

As a result, there shouldn't be any need for Latin abbreviations unless you're writing in Latin, or the journal's style guide requires it.

Comment: Does your advise include _i.e._ and _e.g._? Both are Latin abbreviations frequently used in English academic writing, but given that their use isn't restricted to referencing sources, they are very often not covered by style guides.

Comment: And, thinking of it, _et al._ is of course also a Latin abbreviation that is actively promoted by both the APA and the IEEE referencing style for in-text citations. Perhaps a better wording for your answer would be "stick to the referencing style of the journal your submitting to" instead of giving Latin this much room?

Comment: @Schmuddi I was primarily talking about in-text citations, where et al. wouldn't be used in IEEE, but sure. If their journal's style guide says to use Latin abbreviations in a particular way, they should use it where appropriate.

Comment: The IEEE style guide suggests to use _et al._ with in-text citations if the authors are mentioned: "Azzarello et al. [3] stated that they were unable to determine why …". What about _i.e._ and _e.g._?

Comment: Importing Latin's not necessarily a bad thing when it makes sense, though it'd certainly seem weird when there'd be better terms in English already.  For example, replacing "_see X_" with "_q.v. X_" would seem counterproductive.

Comment: "_i.e._" and "_e.g._" are edge-cases for me.  I kinda got into using them, but seems like there'd be a good argument for dropping "_e.g._" in favor of "_ex._" (including that "_e.g._" can be mistaken for "_i.e._", whereas "_ex._" is generally well-understood).

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned putting "q.v." ("which see") after a citation, and mentioned that it's pretty rare. I'll add that after *two or more* citations you can pluralize it to "qq.v.", which is even rarer.